# Protocol Check is not invoking from success callback of previous protocol check

Tags: javascript, html, custom-protocol

It behaves inconsistent with respect to browsers.

**Google Chrome:** Can invoke first one but cannot invoke another one.

```js
$(function () {
    $("div[href]").click(function (event) {
        debugger;

        window.protocolCheck("abcd:",
        function () {
            console.log('err1')
        }, function () {
            console.log('succ1');
            window.protocolCheck("xyz:",
                function () {
                    console.log('err2');
                }, function () {
                    console.log('succ2');
                });
        });



    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Custom Protocol Detection</title>
</head>

<body id="abcd">
    <h1>Click one of these labels:</h1>
    <a href="#" id="atemp"></a>
    <div href="blahblah:randomstuff"  style="background-color:aquamarine">
        Non-exist protocol
    </div>
    <div href="mailto:johndoe@somewhere.com" style="background-color:aqua">
        Send email
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://github.com/ismailhabib/custom-protocol-detection/blob/master/protocolcheck.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

1. I want to validate in user registry that some protocol exist.
2. If registry not found we download it if found we invoke next protocol.
3. **Library** https://github.com/ismailhabib/custom-protocol-detection/blob/master/protocolcheck.js

And for invoking can we use **protocol check**  library.

Comment: please share the link of library you are using.

Comment: Library is https://github.com/ismailhabib/custom-protocol-detection/blob/master/protocolcheck.js

Answer (score 0):

The second callback is called on success. So, the first check fails, then the second check code will not be invoked.